# Условие для отображение слайдера на определенной странице WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет, есть слайдер MetaSlider, установка его заключается в том что необходимо добавить следующий код на страницу, данный код вставил в header.php:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="4"]'); ?>
```

Как можно прописать условие чтобы этот код срабатывал только на определенной странице?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте условные теги.
Например, если вам нужно вывести слайдер только на главной:

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() ) {
  echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="4"]');
}
?>
```

Про другие условные теги читайте:
[Условные теги в WordPress](https://wp-kama.ru/id_89/uslovnyie-tegi-v-wp.html)
[Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)